# Swift, parse.com: how to pass data from query

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift

I have such query to parse.com.
Why the numObjects variable has different values ​​inside the findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock and on the function exits

```
func searchUserInParse () -> Int {

    var numObjects : Int = 0 // the num return objects from query

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Bets")
    query.whereKey("user", equalTo: "Bob")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: AnyObject[]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if !error {
            numObjects = objects.count
            println(numObjects) // at this point the value = 1
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo)
        }
    }
    println(numObjects) // at this point the value = 0

    return numObjects
}
```

Comment: This is because the block runs on a background thread asynchronously (take a look at the method name). Because it's asynchronous, it returns immediately and moves on to the code after it. This means that the second `println(numObjects)` is called before the above code block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` which runs asynchronously, try using `findObjects` which runs synchronously:

```
//Set up query...
var objects = query.findObjects()
numObjects = objects.count
println(numObjects)
```

Then when running your function, do it like so:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) {
    //Search users
    searchUserInParse()

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        //Show number of objects etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I get Warning: A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread. 
Break on warnParseOperationOnMainThread() to debug.

Answer (score 2):

That's the nature of async code, your function will run the outer code to completion, then some time later (depending on connection speed and query complexity) the completion block will run.

Your calling code should do something like the following:

- create the query
- start the query with a completion block
- show a loading animation
- return (query results still unknown)

Then you should think about the inside of the block:

- check for errors
- update values that the UI is bound to
- tell the UI to refresh

You can't have a function that will return the count, but you could write a function that takes a completion block as a parameter, and executes it in the query completion block. That's a bit more advanced though.

Answer (score 1):

`query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is will be executed asynchronously , the completion block is called after fetching objects. therefore the code after the block called first hence `numObjects` value is 0.

Comment: then what is the solution to it. I mean what if we need to do the processing asynchrously.