# warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I am trying to implement Facebook login with the following code using Parse backend. I need to update _Users table for the logged in user as well but it doesn't works

```
PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions)  { (user, error) -> Void in
if let result = userName["email"] {
    print("user is nil")
} else {
    userName["email"] = user?.email

    //the following line of code never works and causes the warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread
    userName.saveInBackground()
```

I know that the block works in main thread and background jobs are not allowed there, so I tried to use 
    `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) { () -> Void in`
before saveInBackground() but it doesn't even work.

Comment: *before* it? You have to make the call *inside* it. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/24475010/2442804

Comment: this is my code that doesn't work. `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
                        userName.saveInBackground()
                    }
`